# SharedView alternatives for Windows XP x64 (direct connection)

Tags: 64-bit

I'm running Windows XP x64 SP2 and Microsoft SharedView refuses to install on this OS. Could anyone recommend an alternative, preferably free? I only need to share my desktop with one person, so a connection between the two computers should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try join.me.  My team's been using it off and on along with SharedView.  Heads-up -- seems that IE9 RTM might break SharedView.  Two members of my team are experiencing this now.